# Inverting matrix with assumptions

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

I want to invert a matrix that contains some variables, so I thought I should give some assumptions to Mathematica to speed up the process.

How do I assume that $s0,...,s8$ are positive constants between 1 and 10 in the following?

```
Inverse[{{s0, s1, s2}, {s3, s4, s5}, {s6, s7, s8}}]
```

Comment: `Inverse` does not take `Assumptions` as an option, and I rather suspect all functions it uses for handling the symbolic case (e.g. `Together`) do not either. So the `Assuming/Assumptions` framework is not going to be relevant. Moreover I do not see any way in which it would help, for the particulars described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as

```
Assuming[
{s0 > 0, s1 > 0, s2 > 0, s3 > 0, s4 > 0, s5 > 0, s6 > 0, s7 > 0, s8 > 0},
Inverse[{{s0, s1, s2}, {s3, s4, s5}, {s6, s7, s8}}]]
```

For instance, If you get $s0=-1$, then you will get the error

*$Assumptions::fas: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False.*.

Also you can determine the condition

```
s0 > 0 && s0 < 11
```

for all your numbers.

Good Luck.

Comment: These Assumptions does not change anything regarding to speed and to the representation of the result